# ubuntu18.04 vscode kernel module program ERROR: identifier "KBUILD_MODNAME" is undefine

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-18.04

My environment: Ubuntu 18.04, kernel: linux-5.3.0-53 vscode: lastest

Command for fixing *linux/module.h* not *find asm/xxx.h*

```sh
cd /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-53/include

sudo ln -s asm-generic/ asm
```

My *c_cpp_properties.json*

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-53/include",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-53-generic/include",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-53/arch/x86/include",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-53/include/uapi",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "__GNUC__",
                "__KERNEL__"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

My *hello_module.c*, a simple Linux kernel module program.

```c
//a simple linux kernel module program.
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");  //error here

static int hello_init(void){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "hello world\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "goodbye world\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

**then ERROR：**

```
identifier "KBUILD_MODNAME" is undefined
```

How to fix? Please help me..

Comment: Very first step means that you have no proper packages installed. You need to get build kernel package.

Comment: Adding `"MODULE"` in the **defines** section does the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

*KBUILD_MODNAME* is automatically defined by the Makefile when you build your kernel module, so you will not find it anywhere in the kernel header files.

To stop vscode from complaining about undefined KBUILD_MODNAME identifier, just add a dummy definition to your *c_cpp_properties.json* file in the **"defines"** section

```json
"defines": [
    "KBUILD_MODNAME=\"hello_module\"",
    "__GNUC__",
    "__KERNEL__",
    "MODULE"
],
```

That should make vscode happy =)

The value you define for KBUILD_MODNAME does not really matter, since it is automatically defined during the make process.

I have not understood if this is your only problem, or if you also have problems to compile the module.  If yes let me know and we will figure out how to solve that too!

Comment: Hi, after adding this line, the error became `expect a ';'`, the code is the same as the OP's